# Ora 06512/04088 triggers errors when INSERT INTO statement

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm at work for a trigger which provide a "domain" for column `Molteplicità` in a table called `Partecipa` using a function.

The trigger I've created is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dominioMolteplicità
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON partecipa
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF moltepl_valido(:NEW.molteplicità) = 'f' THEN
        RAISE_APPLICAZION_ERROR(-20002, 'Invalid type');
    END IF;
END;
```

which uses the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION motepl_valido(mol VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR IS
BEGIN
    IF regexp_like(LOWER(mol), ' [*]\..[*] ') THEN
        RETURN 't';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'f';
    END IF;
END;
```

Table `Partecipa` has the following columns:

```
CodP INT,
molteplicità VARCHAR2,
codAss INT,
className VARCHAR2,
PRIMARY KEY (codP),
FOREIGN KEY (className) REFERENCES class(name),
FOREIGN KEY (codAss) REFERENCES associazione(cod)`
```

and even though in my `Associazione` table there are rows (in particular codaAss: 42) and in my `Class` table there are rows (in particular className: 'Impiegato')

When I execute the following statement

```
insert into Partecipa(molteplicità, className, codAss) 
values ('*..*', 'Impiegato', 42);
```

I get these errors:

> ORA-20002 INVALID TYPE
>   ORA-06512: AT "dominioMolteplicità", line 3
>   ORA-04088: ERROR DURING EXECUTION OF TRIGGER "dominioMolteplicità"

(Note that if I disable my trigger, the insert statement works properly. There's some problem with the trigger, but I can't find the mistake.)

Comment: Looks like your question is why `'*..*'` doesn't match your regex `' [*]\..[*] '`. It's the spaces.

Comment: There's something sneaky. `*..*` should be accepted by the regular expression, as [link](https://regex101.com/) says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to the trigger.

Your function `motepl_valido` raises `ORA-20002 INVALID TYPE` if the supplied string (in this case `'*..*'`) does not match the regex `' [*]\..[*] '`. It doesn't match because it's missing the required spaces.

Demo showing the effect of a selection of regex patterns (I've added `|` around the patterns to show the leading and trailing spaces):

```
with demo (molteplicita) as
     ( select '*..*' from dual union all
       select ' *..* ' from dual union all
       select ' *x.* ' from dual )
   , patterns (pattern) as
     ( select '[*]\..[*]' from dual union all
       select ' [*]\..[*] ' from dual union all
       select ' *[*]\..[*] *' from dual union all
       select ' *\*\..\* *' from dual )
select '|'||pattern||'|' as pattern
     , '|'||molteplicita||'|' as molteplicita
     , case when regexp_like(molteplicita, pattern) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as matched
from   demo cross join patterns
order by pattern, molteplicita desc;

PATTERN          MOLTEPLICITA MATCHED
---------------- ------------ -------
| *[*]\..[*] *|  |*..*|       Yes
| *[*]\..[*] *|  | *x.* |     No
| *[*]\..[*] *|  | *..* |     Yes

| *\*\..\* *|    |*..*|       Yes
| *\*\..\* *|    | *x.* |     No
| *\*\..\* *|    | *..* |     Yes

| [*]\..[*] |    |*..*|       No
| [*]\..[*] |    | *x.* |     No
| [*]\..[*] |    | *..* |     Yes

|[*]\..[*]|      |*..*|       Yes
|[*]\..[*]|      | *x.* |     No
|[*]\..[*]|      | *..* |     Yes


12 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Beacue your pattern doesn't conform your data

I suppose `regexp_like( lower(mol), '\*..\*')` would be alright, and in this case the values such as `'*=-*'` or `'*34*'` for molteplicità would work.

Btw, even using `'[\*]..[\*]'`(*where backslash used as an escape character*) as the pattern might be possible for the above regular expression.

**Demo :**

```
with t( mol ) as
(
 select '*24*' from dual union all
 select 'B' from dual union all
 select '*=-*' from dual 
)
select 
  case when regexp_like(lower(mol), '\*..\*') then 't' else 'f' end suggested_pattern1,
  case when regexp_like(lower(mol), '[\*]..[\*]') then 't' else 'f' end suggested_pattern2,
  case when regexp_like(lower(mol), '[*]\..[*]') then 't' else 'f' end original_pattern,
  case when regexp_like(lower(mol), '*..*') then 't' else 'f' end anticipated_pattern
  from t;

SUGGESTED_PATTERN1  SUGGESTED_PATTERN2  ORIGINAL_PATTERN  ANTICIPATED_PATTERN
t                   t                   f                 t
f                   f                   f                 t
t                   t                   f                 t
```

P.S. Note that `anticipated_pattern` would fail also ( for `mol = 'B'` in the above sample).